# Select In Select Statement

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

What is an equivalent LINQ query to the following SQL query:

```
Select Id, Name
From Table1 tbl1
Where Id in ( Select Id From Table2)
```

Comment: LINQ is part of C#, the statement you showed is SQL. If you are trying to select the data in C# you need the data in a C# object, not the database. How are you doing that; LINQ to SQL? Entity Framework? ADO.NET?

Comment: Entity Framework in C# Language

Answer (score 3):

You basically described an inner join with selection of rows from one table:

```
var result = from t1 in Table1
             join t2 in Table2
             on t1.Id equals t2.Id
             select new{t1.Id, t1.Name};
```

Next SQL statement will be generated using EF and MS SQL:

```
SELECT t1.Id, t1.Name
FROM Table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Id
```

Note, that if you are selecting non-unique items from `Table2`, you can potentially have duplicates in the `result`. Use next query to avoid this problem, cons: it loads all ids from Table2 into memory, pros: more time efficient. Checkout Felipes answer's, which is also quite good, but has it's own cons discussed in the comment section.

```
var table2Ids = new HashSet<int>(context.Table2.Select(t2 => t2.Id));

var result = context.Table1
                    .Where(t => table2Ids.Contains(t.Id))
                    .Select(t => new{t.Id, t.Name});
```

Comment: Note that technically this should be a left inner join, rather than an inner join.  The results would be different for your code if a given `Id` value exists twice in the second table.

Comment: @Servy why left? `Where Id in ( Select Id From Table2)` should return false if id is not present in the right table, if I'm not mistaken

Comment: Correct, if the ID is not in the second table at all both queries correctly exclude that row.  If there is one row in the second table with the same ID in the first, both queries return the same value for that ID.  If a given ID in the first table appears two, three, or more times in the second table, the OP's query returns that ID value once, your query returns that ID value N times, once for each match.  That may be a problem, potentially.  You could further filter it, but the easier option is to just do a group join and just select the first table's item.

Comment: Got it, thank you very much for the explanation. I'll add my original answer, because it eliminates that problem, but has it's own cons

Answer (score 1):

try using the `Contains` method:

```
var query = from c in db.Table1
            where db.Table2.Select(x => x.Id).Contains(c.Id)
            select new { c.Id, c.Name };

var result = query.ToList();
```

Comment: does it has n*m complexity?

Comment: @IlyaIvanov In theory yes, and if it were linq to objects, it would be god awful.  In practice, this will be translated into SQL very much like the code in the OP, and the DB engine is smart enough to optimize this into a more proper algorithm, such as yours, internally, thus preventing it from being so awful.  (At least in theory; this should be tested with your specific query provider and database to be sure.)  Having proper indexes on columns also make a big deal here.

Comment: @Servy I've just tried that code with EF and MSSQL, It creates `... WHERE EXISTS(SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY] FROM Table2 AS t2 WHERE t1.Id = t2.Id)`. Are you sure this will be optimized by the engine? (asking because I'm not sure enough about that )

Comment: @IlyaIvanov No, I'm not sure, which is why I said you should actually verify that the particular database being used does indeed have an appropriate translation for this.  You'd need to look at what the DB does with that SQL though, in addition to what SQL the query provider creates.

Comment: I agree. For me it's hard to test what engine does with that query. I haven't done this at all. I guess optimization will definitely take place. Have never gone deeper, than sql query.